# FSC does not deployed Action Plan

Tags: managed-package, permission-sets, object, financial-services-cloud

It is supossed that Financial Services Cloud deploy the Action Plan functionality. In my case, I have already installed and configured FSC but I can't see the Action Plan object in Object manager neither the ActionPlans permission set.

What can be happening in my org?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The Action Plans in Financial Services cloud is only available if your org has Financial Service [Enterprise](https://www.salesforce.com/editions-pricing/financial-services-cloud/) and unlimited license. You will get a specific permission set in your org if you have purchased FSC.